# Transaction Security Policies for ApiEvent not working in my Sandbox

Tags: transaction-security-policy

I have created and enabled a transaction security policy for `ApiEvent` using Apex in my developer sandbox. For my testing, I just added system.debug statements to see what kind of parameters I receive in the `evaluate()` method.
I am trying to intercept any call (SOQL / SOSL / dataload) made from Workbench in this to potentially block / allow certain objects in the future.
I have found that when I am testing from Workbench the Apex class configured in the transaction security policy never gets called. I do not see the debug logs captured.

Here's my code:

```
global class SomeonetriedtouseAPIEventCondition implements TxnSecurity.EventCondition {

    public boolean evaluate(SObject event) {
        System.debug('In SomeonetriedtouseAPIEventCondition.evaluate: '+event);
        switch on event {
            
            when APIEvent apiEvent {
                return handleApiEvent(apiEvent);
            }
            when null {
                // Trigger action if event is null
                return true;
             }
             when else {
                // Trigger action for unhandled events
                return true;
             }
        }        
    }
    
     private boolean handleApiEvent(ApiEvent apiEvent){
         System.debug('In SomeonetriedtouseAPIEventCondition.handleApiEvent');
         System.debug('Application: '+apiEvent.Application);
         System.debug('Client: '+apiEvent.Client);
         System.debug('UserAgent : '+apiEvent.UserAgent);
         System.debug('ConnectedAppId: '+apiEvent.ConnectedAppId);
         System.debug('RowsProcessed  : '+apiEvent.RowsProcessed);
         System.debug('Username : '+apiEvent.Username);
         return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: have you bound the apex event handler to the TSP? Is it enabled? See [steps 4-5 and 10](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.enhanced_transaction_security_apex.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. Yes, I have done it. Spoke to Salesforce Support today, the support engineer was as surprised as I was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs were available as `Automated Process` User instead of my User